# How to identify Project_Code, File_Name, File_Format. and create new folder structure based of this

Tags: python

I'm not a good python programmer but a good max scripter.
I have been trying to automate a process of cleaning up max files which are corrupted.
There are total of 88000 files which needs to be cleaned up.

The files I get to clean up are in .zip format, with naming conventions like this.

**"Project_Name_File_Name_File_Format.zip"**

The automation process of loading the .max file and cleaning up the corruption is done via max script.

What i have been trying to do is Create a folder structure like so:

Project Name--> File Name --> File Format

I have been at it for the last two week, still no  good progress on this front.

Here is the basic code I have been trying to get it working at least identifying the file names with file formats. I tried a dictionary method for project names and file formats. Still no luck, I created a list to string and then I landed in a loop of creating lists to strings and strings to lists.

```
import os

files = os.listdir('path\\')  # Set location where all the .zip files are present.
files_zip = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.zip')]
for file_name in files_zip:
    print(file_name)
token = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0].split("_")
#print(token)
new_token = token[1:-1]
print(new_token)
new_file_name = "_".join(new_token)
print(new_file_name)
```

**Another set of code i tried to do is here**

```
import os

path = 'path\\'
files = os.listdir(path)  # Set location where all the .zip files are present.

# Dictionary Project Keys and Values
project_dic = {'ABC': 'Apple Bucket Cake', 'XYZ': 'Xerox Yacht Zoo'}

# Dictionary for File Formats
file_formats = {'FBX': 'FBX', 'OBJ': 'OBJ', '3ds Max': '3ds Max'}

# Looking for the files which ends with Project Names (prj_lst)
files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.zip')]
# print(files_txt)

prj_lstToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in files_txt])
name_set = prj_lstToStr.split('prj_lstToStr')
# print(name_set)

#print("Project_List : " + str(name_set))
res = [ele if len(ele) > 0 else () for ele in [[key for key in project_dic if key in sub] for sub in name_set]]
#print("Project_Matching_Keys : " + str(res))
string_key = ''.join(str(res))

format_list = [ele if len(ele) > 0 else () for ele in [[key for key in file_formats if key in sub] for sub in name_set]]
#print("Format_Matching_Keys : " + str(format_list))
format_key = ''.join(str(format_list))

token = files_txt
```

Comment: Please post the results and/or errors you are getting when you run your code.

Comment: @FloWil 
Here is the out I get for the first set of code:

>>> 
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***
ABC_Warren_Vidic_Head_OBJ.zip
ALS_Sand_Mound_pr_ann_0479_c_OBJ.zip
GRT_ENV-SPE-GRP-SK-ExplorationChestPMC-A_3ds Max.zip
KLS_alpha-GEN_PRO_HedgePotPlanter_Group_01A_2021-03-31_FBX.zip
MISC_gho_caucasian-mattE_(wise)_OBJ.zip
MISC_W_ATT_SalvoXL_FBX.zip
MISC_XA-20_Razorback_JetFighter_3ds Max.zip
WLD_ENV-GLO-PRO-Bivouac-TacticalSmartphone-A_3ds Max.zip
XYZ_WPN_ATT_MAG_MagpulPMAGMOE_FBX.zip
WPN_ATT_MAG_MagpulPMAGMOE

Comment: I don't have errors but i want to get out of a loop of creating a list to string and string to list

Comment: I assume from your code that you know all the possible project names and file formats. Can you give some examples of the input and expected file names?

Comment: @jacob here is the expected result
Project Name (First Folder) 'Apple Bucket Cake'
File Name (inside Project Folder) 'Warren_Vidic_Head'
File Format (inside File Name Folder) 'OBJ'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, so I will delete this answer if it is not correct. From what I understand:

```
input = ["BC_Warren_Vidic_Head_OBJ.zip",
         "ALS_Sand_Mound_pr_ann_0479_c_OBJ.zip",
         "GRT_ENV-SPE-GRP-SK-ExplorationChestPMC-A_3dsMax.zip",
         "KLS_alpha-GEN_PRO_HedgePotPlanter_Group_01A_2021-03-31_FBX.zip",
         "MISC_gho_caucasian-mattE_(wise)_OBJ.zip",
         "MISC_W_ATT_SalvoXL_FBX.zip",
         "MISC_XA-20_Razorback_JetFighter_3dsMax.zip",
         "WLD_ENV-GLO-PRO-Bivouac-TacticalSmartphone-A_3dsMax.zip",
         "XYZ_WPN_ATT_MAG_MagpulPMAGMOE_FBX.zip"]

for inp in input:
    splitted = inp.split('_')
    project_name = splitted[0]
    file_name = '_'.join(splitted[1:-1])
    file_format = splitted[-1].split('.')[0]
    path = f'./{project_name}/{file_name}/{file_format}'
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
```